# paper.js onFrame method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, paperjs

i'm trying to learn some [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/), and its [onFrame event](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#onframe) doesn't work with me :(
In code below i create 30 random shapes on canvas, and trying to rotate each one of them by onFrame method, but nothing is happening, paths stand fixed.

```
var len = 30;
var array = new Array();
var rand;
var colors = ['#fbff00', '#99ff37', '#00eeff', '#374afe', '#ff005e'];
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {      
    rand = getRandom(0, 4);
    switch (rand) {
        case 0: // if 0, create circle
            var path = new Path.Circle({
                center: [getRandom(30, scrwidth - 30), getRandom(30, scrheight - 30)],
                radius: 30
            });
            path.fillColor = colors[getRandom(0, 4)];
            array.push(path);
            break;
//and some others in the same way
    }
}
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function onFrame(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var item = project.activeLayer.children[i];         
        item.rotate(3);
    }
}
paper.view.draw();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done with that! 
Code should be ended that way:

```
view.onFrame = function(event) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        var item = project.activeLayer.children[i]; 
        item.rotate(3); 
    } 
} 
paper.view.draw();
```

Comment: This works because this is the right way to do it **when you are using plain js** instead of paperscript.

Comment: Where do you get the view variable from? `paper.view.onFrame = function(){}` doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: if you call `paper.install(window);` before running any other code, the paper object is copied over to the global scope, and you access directly from the `view` object. I believe the last line here should be `view.draw();` though this isn't necessary to call after the initial call to `draw` is made, as the onFrame function redraws after executing automatically.